# Pandas merge several rows with different columns into one row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe `df` with following characteristic

| store_id | city_id | sales_A | sales_B | sales_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| STORE01 | CITY99 | 100 Item | None | None |
| STORE01 | CITY99 | None | 200 Order | None |
| STORE01 | CITY99 | None | None | 300 Client |
| STORE01 | CITY99 | 150 Order | None | 300 Client |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

All rows will has same characteristics, where same `store id` and `city ID` has 1 row or more:

- row 1 : sales A has value, other None
- row 2 : sales B has value, other None
- row 3 : sales C has value, other None
- row 4 : sales A has value (but different with row 1), other None

Note that the value is not number, they are string, and must be kept as string

Ordering of rows might be different, but basically each has 1 or more rows, depends on sales.

In pandas,how can I merge them into one row, so the result dataset will be something like this :

| store_id | city_id | sales_A | sales_B | sales_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| STORE01 | CITY99 | 100 Item, 150 Order | 200 Order | 300 Client |

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with remove `None` values and duplicates, last join values by `,` in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
#if None are strings convert them to NoneType
#df = df.mask(df == 'None', None)


f = lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().unique())
df = df.groupby(['store_id','city_id'], as_index=False).agg(f)
print (df)
  store_id city_id              sales_A    sales_B     sales_C
0  STORE01  CITY99  100 Item, 150 Order  200 Order  300 Client
```

Comment: Sorry, updated question. 1 combination can has more than one row on sales_A, or sales_B, or sales_C. Your approach work if I only has one NaN value per group